# Indentation in Beamer Frametitle

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, line-breaking, frame-title

I'm coming here looking for help because I've tried in every way to correct the error in the attached figure. When dealing with a long title, the second line suffers an unnecessary indentation. I wanted to make the second row line up equally with the first row. I'm using the Goettingen theme.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With that clues, the answer only can be "stop doing whatever you are doing to change the default output":

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Anomalies, Filtering and Statistics Significance}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```